# Placeholder option on select element with default selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Bit of a weird one, not sure if this is possible or not.

The system I am working on has a sort by select element which has 'Recommended Products' as the selected option on load as this is the order in which they'd like the products to be when a user hits the page, but they also want it to say 'Sort By' be default so that it's obvious this is a sort by element. Unfortunately I can't change the core HTML, I can only modify via jQuery/Javascript.

Just wondering if there was a way to do this with jQuery or not, as the method I've tried have interfered with the default select so far. Is it even possible to have a default placeholder as well as another option selected to dictate the load in state?

Cheers!

Current HTML

```
<select id="sort-by-select">
  <option value="#" selected="">Recommended Products</option>
  <option value="#">Price (High to Low)</option>
  <option value="#">Price (Low to High)</option>
  <option value="#">Newest In</option>
  <option value="#">Most Popular</option>
</select>
```

Desired HTML

```
<select id="sort-by-select">
  <option value="#" selected="" disabled="disabled">Sort By</option>
  <option value="#" selected="">Recommended Products</option>
  <option value="#">Price (High to Low)</option>
  <option value="#">Price (Low to High)</option>
  <option value="#">Newest In</option>
  <option value="#">Most Popular</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Why not `<label for="sort-by-select">Sort by</label><select id="sort-by-select"><option value="" selected>Recommended product</option>`

Comment: You can't have them both selected (and shown) simultaneously, unfortunately.You'd need to pick one or the other, or add additional HTML as suggested by @mplungjan

Comment: Also `selected=true" disabled="disabled"`

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, you can only have one default/selected option. What you could do instead is add a label via jQuery, using [`.insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/):

```js
$(function() {
  var $label = $('<label>').text('Sort By:').attr('for', 'sort-by-select');
  $label.insertBefore($('#sort-by-select'));
});
```

```css
label { margin-right: 5px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sort-by-select">
  <option value="#" selected="">Recommended Products</option>
  <option value="#">Price (High to Low)</option>
  <option value="#">Price (Low to High)</option>
  <option value="#">Newest In</option>
  <option value="#">Most Popular</option>
</select>
```

Alternatively, you could prepend "Sort by" to every option in the select, using [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2):

```js
$(function() {
  $('#sort-by-select option').text(function () {
    return 'Sort by: ' + $(this).text();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sort-by-select">
  <option value="#" selected="">Recommended Products</option>
  <option value="#">Price (High to Low)</option>
  <option value="#">Price (Low to High)</option>
  <option value="#">Newest In</option>
  <option value="#">Most Popular</option>
</select>
```